# How to create a table like this using only HTML?

Tags: html, html-table, attributes

Someone please help me creating a table like this using only HTML.[image: table structure image]

I can only create the first two rows,but the third one is difficult for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your Desired Table :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        table {
            border: 5px solid black;
            table-layout: fixed;
            width: 200px;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        th,
        td {
            border: 5px solid black;
            width: 100px;
            overflow: hidden;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td colspan="4">2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">3</td>
            <td colspan="2">4</td>
            <td colspan="2">5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>6</td>
            <td colspan="2">7</td>
            <td>8</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Answer (score 0):

This table is just HTML, it's not exactly what you want but it can be helpful for your need.

```html
<table border = "2">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td > 1 </td>
            <td colspan = "12"> 2 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2"> 3 </td>
            <td colspan = "5"> 4 </td>
            <td colspan = "5"> 5 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan = "3"> 6 </td>
            <td colspan = "6" > 7 </td>
            <td colspan = "3"> 8 </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.